# Check for secretmanager resource labels on condition?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, common-expression-language

Since `secretmanager.googleapis.com/Secret` or `secretmanager.googleapis.com/SecretVersion` doesn't allow attaching tags, thus not allowing `resource.matchTag` to be used as a IAM condition, I was hoping to be able to check for the existing labels (or even annotations) on the secret itself to serve as a tag.

I tried, in ascending order from the most naive attempt to the desperate one:

```
resource.labels.tag == "..."
api.getAttribute('secretmanager.googleapis.com/Secret', {})['labels']['tag'] == ".."
api.getAttribute('secretmanager.googleapis.com/Secret/labels', {})['tag'] == ".."
api.getAttribute('secretmanager.googleapis.com/Secret/labels/tag', "") == ".."
```

None of those worked, even though the documentation says that `api.getAttribute()` works for secretmanager

Answer (score 0):

Hei, just come accross this post and did some testing. The correct syntax seems to be:

```
api.getAttribute('secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-id>/secrets', []).hasOnly(['labels.<label-key>=<label-value>'])
```